# Adding based on text string in a cell in a table

Tags: excel, search, formula, vlookup

So I have a table with description lines like this: EFT VISA RF#509723083734 04/07 ENDICIA POSTAGE (EMS) 650-321-2640.

What I'd like to be able to do is add up all the amounts with descriptions containing "Endicia".

I tried =VLOOKUP(SEARCH("endicia",D9,0)="true",D2:F12,3) but that didn't work.
I tried using SumIf instead, with similar lack of success.

Any advice would be much appreciated

IF helpful, the description is in column D and the amount is in column E.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add an additional column, you can add one in that only counts the number if the keyword ("ENDICIA") is found in the cell (otherwise return 0).

`=IFERROR(IF(FIND("ENDICIA",D1),E1,0),0)`

From there you just need to sum the column where you put this formula.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(D:D,"*ENDICIA*",E:E)
```